# When does object pointed by 'Example.class' come into existence?

Tags: java, eclipse

Below is the program:

```
package annotationtype;

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args){

    }
}
```

got compiled with below byte code.

```
Classfile /D:/git/Java_programming/JavaCode/bin/annotationtype/Example.class
  ......
  Compiled from "Example.java"
public class annotationtype.Example
  .......
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Class              #2             // annotationtype/Example
   #2 = Utf8               annotationtype/Example
   #3 = Class              #4             // java/lang/Object
   ......
  #18 = Utf8               SourceFile
  #19 = Utf8               Example.java
{
  public annotationtype.Example();
  ........
  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  ......
}
SourceFile: "Example.java"
```

Using eclipse editor, In `main()` method, if I type,

`Example.`, eclipse editor immediately provides `class` member of type `Class<annotationtype.Example>`

My understanding is,

below byte code,

```
#1 = Class              #2             // annotationtype/Example
 ..
#3 = Class              #4             // java/lang/Object
```

indicates creation of object of type `Class<annotationtype.Example>` pointed by member `Class<annotationtype.Example> class` during initialisation phase of `class Example`, something **functionally equivalent** to:

```
public class annotationtype.Example{
    public static Class<annotationtype.Example> class;
    {
        class = Class.forName("annotationtype.Example")
    }
    ......
}
```

Is my understanding correct about,

the phase at which object(creation) of type `Class<annotationtype.Example>` comes into existence, that is pointed by `Example.class`?

Comment: *There is no member named “class”*.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are confusing artifacts of the Java programming language with items of the constant pool of a class file holding Java byte code.

Class literals of the form `type.class`, as well as an access to the length of an array of the form `array.length` may look like a member access in the source code but have nothing to do with real class members.

E.g. when you write `array.length`, it will get compiled to a bytecode instruction `arraylength` dedicated to retrieve the length of an array at runtime without actually specifying how a JVM remembers lengths of arrays. That’s implementation dependent.

A class literal is more complicated. E.g. when you write `int.class`, there is nothing to query. Instead, the compiler knows that it has to read the `static` field `Integer.TYPE` to get the runtime value and that’s how this class literal gets compiled, as a field access to `Integer.TYPE`. In contrast, class literals of reference types are compiled using an `ldc` instruction pointing to a constant pool entry which has nothing to to with fields.

The constant pool of a class does not contain Java objects in the first place. It contains linkage information. Some entries might get associated with a Java runtime instance on their first use but the way it works is intentionally unspecified. That’s up to the JVM. These entries serve different purposes, i.e. a Class entry can be used to specify a super class, an implemented interface or a class, whose member is accessed by a method invocation or field access.

That’s why your `Example` class file contains such a Class entry. It’s there because the class uses it to describe itself. Even if there is no class literal `Example.class` at all. Consequently, a `Class` instance describing the class `Example` is create [when the class is loaded](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass-java.lang.String-). A `ClassLoader` remembers all loaded classes and they will be used when the same name is resolved using the same loader.

Note that when another class contains a class literal of the form `Example.class`, it will have it’s own Class entry for that class within its own constant pool. The runtime evaluation of the class literal *may* trigger the loading and hence creating of the `Class` instance when it has not been loaded before. Otherwise, it gets resolved to the already loaded class via the class loader.

Comment: For primitive types, a name would work. But reference types consist of a name *and* an initiating class loader at runtime. As said in my answer, a class loader remembers all classes defined on it and will resolve the same name to the same `Class` instance, but a different class loader might define a different runtime class with the same name. So a name can be ambiguous. In other words, there is no problem passing the result of `Class.forName` to `getConstructor` if your source is a `String`. But calling `Class.getName()` and resolving it in a different context may produce a different class.

Comment: @Holger I did not get this statement: "a class loader remembers all classes defined on it and will resolve the same name to the same Class instance, but a different class loader might define a different runtime class with the same name. So a name can be ambiguous.", *different runtime class with same name*?

Comment: Yes, at runtime, there can be more than one class with the same name. That depends on the `ClassLoader`s. Compare [JVMS §5.3](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.3): “*At run time, a class or interface is determined not by its name alone, but by a pair: its binary name (§4.2.1) and its defining class loader.*” See also [JLS §12.2](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.2)

Comment: Don’t assume that the two classes named `X` are the same, just because they have the same name. They *might* be derived from the same class file, but it’s also possible, that they are different versions of an evolved class or they are simply unrelated. Frameworks like OSGi may load non-exported types multiple times in different loaders to ensure that the bundles are decoupled. Further, unloading a bundle in order to load a newer version, works exactly that way, there are tons of dynamic frameworks doing this. As long as the old loader hasn’t garbage collected, both versions exist at runtime.